# Edit text value + alert dialog edit text value and save it to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making app where I want to get value of one edit text of one activity
and value on alert dialog edit text and save it to the another activity.
I am using hash map for that i have 4 string in my pojo class.
[image: this is my first text box]

in this text box I am taking mobile number from user when user click on save then [image: this dialog box open]
when user click on save then this dialog box are open and i want to take name from user and save it to the another activity . 
I am using hash map here. I want to ask how to get this type of data my mobile number is on one fragment name on alert dialog fragment.

Comment: Can you show code which create `AlertDialog`? It's created in same activity or another

Comment: AlertDialog created on another fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in different ways:

1. You can use SharedPreferences.
2. You can pass Create an object of your class in first fragment with your Phone No, and then pass that object while creating the alert. Now update the value with the Nickname. And finally use this object as you want.

In case alert dialog is present in another fragment, you can pass the object created in first fragment to the second fragment using Bundle.